# Jquery Not Passing Value to php page

Tags: php, jquery

I am coding a php album to preview the images and comments i am using Jquery below is code

php

```
$photo .="<div class=\"imagearray\"><span>".$imagerealname ."</span><br/><div class=\"imagecontent\"><image src='uploads/thumb_".$query['imagesrc']."' alt='image' id='".$query['ImageSN']."' /></div>share delete</div>";
```

To call images from Database

then click on any image jquery function executes

```
// display photo preview ajaxy
    $('.imagearray .imagecontent img').click(function (event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

        getPhotoPreviewAjx($(this).attr('id'));
    });
})
```

getPhotoPreviewAjx is

```
function getPhotoPreviewAjx(id) {

        var id = id;
        alert(id);  
    $.post('commentblock.php',
            { action: 'get_info', Id: id },
        function(data){
            $('#photo_preview .pleft').html(data.data1);
            $('#photo_preview .pright').html(data.data2);
            $('#photo_preview').show();
        }, "json"
    );
};
```

this code is working till `alert(id);` and next i dont think it is passing values to commentblock.php

starting of commentblock.php is

```
if( $_POST['action'] == "get_info" &&  isset($_POST['Id']))
{
echo $_POST['id'];
```

and it is not working need some guideness struck here :(

Comment: Could you add another alert in postback call? function(data){ console.info(data); ....

Comment: What is `var id = id;` supposed to do?

Comment: i tried that tell me something will this show in console if yes than nothing in console

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was debugging to check jquery passing id or not

Comment: Your AJAX call is just echoing the id.  So, `data.data1` won't exist.

Comment: yes as it is my problem ajax call only working to echo the id not passing value to php page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(After debugging)

The javascript works correctly. There is an error or something stopping it working correctly in server side code.

Comment: Nothing no result id and action are empty  any other way through jquery to make that call?

Comment: Add `console.log($(this).attr('id'));` before `getPhotoPreviewAjx($(this).attr('id'));` and tell me what it outputs to the developer console.

Comment: Can you see the POST data sent by the AJAX request in the network section of your web browsers developer tools?

Comment: in developer tools i can only see 2 which is img id and problem is in function getPhotoPreviewAjx i appreciate your help

Comment: I can see "action:get_info, Id:2" being posted from the ajax request.

Comment: If I ignore the success response event handler, the code in `getPhotoPreviewAjx()` looks correct. Try putting together a form that posts the data to the `commentblock.php` file, and see if you get the correct `$_POST` variables (or construct a POST request using fiddler, etc). This can help us rule out the web browser / js as being the issue.

Comment: Thank God Jquery was Good it is kinda Working now i played with php code debugging around and it responsed back just hoping i got it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

try changing `{ action: 'get_info', Id: id },` to `{ data: $("form").serialize() }` (I'm assuming your data is coming from inputs in a form element named 'get_info' and 'Id')

Comment: no form here like i pasted in my Question id is coming from Img click function